# Why did I get a chat suspension?

Tags: support, chat

Is there any place where the official reason is provided? I got no communications.

Comment: "I got no communications" - unlikely.

Comment: Where can I find the communications?

Comment: @Bart: can you help me to understand the reason? A 2 days ban chat is not a problem, but why?

Comment: Contact your friendly neighbourhood (community) moderators and ask them. You and I might be able to take a guess, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Once again, don't ask me, ask those who might actually know. Any answer by me is a guess. And I suck at guessing.

Comment: What? "On question"? But you were chat-suspended? And you can't retract flags.

Comment: @Bart: ok, but how can I ask I didn't get (or at least I cannot see) any message telling me who had suspended me.

Comment: You never get to see who suspended you. It doesn't matter. All that matters is that you are. I'd say you simply move on, but if it's a mystery you want to solve, there is a contact link at the bottom of the website. Or be patient and see if you get an official reply here. However, such things are usually best handled in private communication.

Comment: @nicael: I've been chat suspended some hours after speaking with some users in a completely normal way..

Comment: I'm not a moderator on Meta.SE, but this might be a clue: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2727740#2727740

Comment: @Bart: I will take a deep breath and avoid any polemic, but...

Comment: @Bart: ps: I've seen on meta this post: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2729602#2729602 and your answer. If ProgramFOX feels to answer he can. I won't be polemic at all.

Comment: You don't need an answer from regular users. Heck, you don't need a public answer.

Comment: @Bart: how can I clean my reputation? this is what I need. By deleting this answer I will help it?

Comment: Stop worrying about your reputation and move on. Stop annoying people about worrying about it and move on. Get a thicker skin and move on. tl;dr move on.

Comment: @Bart: ok, I will follow your advice. I hope it will help. Otherwise I will have to take a lot of deep breath :D

Answer (score 10):

It could be because you opened a number of chat rooms with some users to speak how the life is harsh, and you have really bad reputation there, etc. Once one user got annoyed, you started the same conversation with another user. Maybe it became a bit irritating.

Comment: This happened a lot in the past. Now I've only explained a few users my reasons after they and - except one user - the reason had been very well accepted. I also spoke a lot with some of them getting advice and compliments. I think the problem is another.. a flag for mod's attention that I put.

Comment: @Jan Yeah, it appears to be [earlier](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1928409#1928409), I just performed a small search and didn't notice. So I am removing it from my answer.

Comment: This is the room where I was speaking in a completely pacifical way with 2 users: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/807/crypt-of-the-tavern-spectator-lobby

Comment: In this room http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/773/low-quality-posts-hq there is written: 
Spam Flag Request for meta.stackexchange.com/a/… by rene from Tavern on the Meta Does it relate to my suspension?

Comment: Shouldn't you also mention the other rooms you created and invited users to? Just try to tell the complete story and not only the part that suits you. And don't drag me into this. My spam flag has nothing to do with it, it is not related

Comment: Stop asking those who did not suspend you.

Comment: @rene: I did mention: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244596/why-did-i-get-a-chat-suspension?noredirect=1#comment799556_244598. ps: have you read the content of that chatrooms?

Comment: @rene: the real question is: how can I clean my reputation? Deleting this question will be helpful? Bearing the chat ban in silence? Tell me and I will do.

Comment: @Revious Wait out your chat ban and, most importantly, **do not** behave the same way you have been. Don't ping a bunch of people for no reason, don't invite multiple people into separate chat rooms, etc. Stay quiet and observe how other people behave in chat for a while if you must, but whatever you do, don't keep going on like you have been.

Comment: @AnnaLear: ok, Anna, no problem. Can I ask you just a great favor? Before judging me strictly, read some lines of the private with Bart or Vogel or BenCollins, ask their opinion. And only then express a judgement like: "for no reason". You can say that you have already done, but I'm pretty sure you didn't. Thanks.

Comment: @Revious Not saying *all* of your pings and invitations were unwarranted, but enough of them were that folks got tired. So don't do that.

Comment: @AnnaLear: thanks.. I will be more careful, but I'd also would appreciate you to realize that I'm not insisting as in the past. I opened each of the 4 chats **only** after unpolite sentences towards me. I've been banned and no one else. Some behavior from members were very unpolite, near to lack of education, for the reputation I had built. I guess also this is very annoying and I guess no one would appreciate that bias and amount of prejudice. In 4 of 5 chats **my reasons got** totally **accepted**. Please, take also this into account, if you mind to be a fair community. Thanks for listening.